# What is Reality TV called in German?

Tags: translation

Does the German language have any ironic terms to denote what is called "reality tv" in English?

Comment: It's simply named "Reality-Show".

Comment: Lol. English gives out the trashiest loan words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms

> Reality TV
>   Reality Show

are used as foreign words in German language, but they not necessarily have an ironic touch. Really ironic is:

> **Sozialporno**

Literally: *social porn*
Although it contains *-porno*, this word has no sexual connotation (like "food porn" also has no sexual connotation). It is just because of presenting something to a wide audience, that normally is not shown to the public.

Comment: Die Aussage, es gäbe keinen sexuellen Unterton, halte ich für gewagt. Würdest Du den Begriff in einem Kindergarten benutzen? Damit zusammen hängt die Behauptung, der Ausdruck sei ironisch. Ironie ist feiner Spott - Sozialporno halte ich für derben Spott.

Comment: @userunknown: In einem Kindergarten: Jederzeit. Zu Kindern: Eher nicht, weil sie mit dem Wort *Porno* vermutlich nicht viel anfangen können, und ich Kindern das Wort nicht erklären will (*Porno* hat ja durchaus einen sexuellen Unterton. *Sozialporno* aber trotzdem nicht). Zu *feiner/grober Spott*: a) Ich keine keine Definition von Ironie, die einen solchen Unterschied macht. b) Wie definierst du den Unterschied zwischen feinem und derbem Spott?

Comment: b) Derber Spott kann nicht übersehen werden. a) Duden zu Ironie: feiner, verdeckter Spott, mit dem jemand etwas dadurch zu treffen sucht, dass er es unter dem augenfälligen Schein der eigenen Billigung lächerlich macht. Übliche Fragestellung in Kreuzworträtseln

Comment: @userunknown Nur, weil man einen Begriff nicht im Kindergarten benutzen würde, kann man nicht schließen, er habe sexuelle Untertöne. *Scheißen* würde ich dort auch nicht benutzen aber der Begriff trägt keine sexuellen Untertöne.

Comment: @Jan Darf ich für Dich die Logik ausbreiten: Nicht alles, was Tabu ist, ist sexuell, auch wenn es sexuelle Tabus gibt. Porno ist im Kindergarten aber ein Tabu, weil Pornos in die Sphäre des Sexuellen gehören. Porno bedeutet immer Porno, entweder unmittelbar, oder als Metapher. In der Metapher ist die ursprüngliche Bedeutung erhalten und kann erst mit der Zeit verblassen (das geht auf keine Kuhhaut). Meine Aussage war nicht, dass alles, was im Kindergarten tabu ist, sexuell ist, aber dass es bei Porno so ist. Weswegen ist Porno sonst im Kindergarten tabu?

Answer (score 1):

Da wir englische Terminologien verwenden, die gar nicht englisch sind, könnte *Skripted reality* sein was Du suchst. Allerdings ist nicht die ganze  Phrase ironisch, sondern nur der Reality-Part, der vom Skripted ganz offensichtlich negiert wird.